# curl: (60) Certificate type not approved for application where wget works

Tags: curl, https, certificate

## Question

Please suggest if this is curl specific issue or if some options are missing to get it work.

CURL shows **60) Certificate type not approved for application** error to access kubelet healthz endpoint whereas wget has no issue.

```
$ sudo wget -v -S -O - \
>   --ca-cert=/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt \
>   --certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt \
>   --private-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key \
> https://ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal:10250/healthz
--2017-12-27 06:55:53--  https://ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal:10250/healthz
Resolving ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal (ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal)... 172.31.4.117
Connecting to ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal (ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal)|172.31.4.117|:10250... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Wed, 27 Dec 2017 06:55:53 GMT
  Content-Length: 2
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Length: 2 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

$ sudo curl -ivL \
>     --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt \
>     --key  /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key \
>     --cacert /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt \
> https://ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal:10250/healthz
*   Trying 172.31.4.117...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal (172.31.4.117) port 10250 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal@1514006010
*   start date: Dec 23 05:13:30 2017 GMT
*   expire date: Dec 23 05:13:30 2018 GMT
*   common name: ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal@1514006010
*   issuer: CN=ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal@1514006010
* NSS error -8101 (SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_CERT_TYPE)
* Certificate type not approved for application.
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Certificate type not approved for application.
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

***curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server*** and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

kubelet generates a self-signed certificate if a CA is not explicitly specified with an option.

**--tls-cert-file string**

> File containing x509 Certificate used for serving HTTPS (with intermediate certs, if any, concatenated after server cert). If --tls-cert-file and --tls-private-key-file are not provided, a self-signed certificate and key are generated for the public address and saved to the directory passed to --cert-dir.

### Research

Found the related K8S topics.

- [Change self signed certificates to not include extended key usage #311](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/311)
- [Switch to wget for integration apiserver checks](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/service-catalog/commit/11f18f3d17a4ab5d4789ff38ce3f320edf5d77d2)

> The NSS encryption library does not allow a CA to be used with the extended key usage present, at least in the way we are currently doing so. The generated self signed certificates extension section looks like:

```
...
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Certificate Sign
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:localhost, IP Address:127.0.0.1, IP Address:127.0.0.1
```

> Testing with the extended key usage removed allows curl to work, but simply switching to wget will allow integration tests to work on Fedora immediately.

#### The kubelet.crt server certificate causing the issue.

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal@1514006010
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 23 05:13:30 2017 GMT
            Not After : Dec 23 05:13:30 2018 GMT
        Subject: CN=ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal@1514006010
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d5:48:65:86:4e:ec:08:a1:b1:26:4b:da:7c:e0:
                    d9:d0:16:96:93:9e:c0:f3:78:cb:27:a9:e1:99:d2:
                    10:73:70:e5:1e:ee:03:1a:55:51:29:c6:2e:62:71:
                    d9:c2:72:19:d3:36:41:9b:ef:74:ac:20:97:25:1b:
                    63:55:96:07:4d:02:01:c9:44:7d:f9:63:2b:50:98:
                    2a:fb:b7:03:0d:96:6d:6a:36:9d:93:ad:2c:6a:87:
                    7d:b8:aa:22:ca:f2:c4:a6:90:24:2b:4c:94:d1:4a:
                    3c:0d:c5:fa:48:fb:e5:82:30:17:f9:67:3a:1d:9b:
                    85:7a:bc:e9:e9:79:48:0e:53:41:fc:64:3a:c3:c1:
                    7e:ae:51:23:17:8e:db:1e:4c:99:56:a4:77:ad:74:
                    64:64:ab:a7:84:02:40:ec:c8:b1:51:2b:b3:80:7e:
                    b2:51:68:5c:d2:40:9d:f3:54:b9:76:2d:47:ea:f4:
                    51:c6:03:e9:c4:63:5c:5a:a7:7e:9a:97:89:45:99:
                    e8:a0:9b:5d:1d:15:94:f9:c9:2a:a4:19:a2:07:25:
                    2b:e6:0e:50:63:c0:6e:f9:a0:a7:ce:4a:ca:97:17:
                    64:2f:8a:e2:39:d5:e2:c9:c7:c4:53:f1:6e:14:22:
                    ca:02:cb:8a:0c:47:68:31:f2:0b:20:2c:a3:a5:5f:
                    cd:95
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Certificate Sign
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         bc:84:b2:5c:c1:a5:52:b7:03:ae:9c:53:47:4b:ca:8b:4a:90:
         7f:41:0f:09:ff:77:5e:cc:7c:2c:0c:bc:37:71:c9:22:4e:7f:
         eb:9f:a9:f8:04:1d:8d:39:67:52:46:9c:3b:dc:d8:1f:b0:00:
         64:ed:2f:bf:8f:4c:8c:f2:6b:96:ec:99:66:19:39:1d:11:77:
         52:6b:a8:f4:88:e1:ad:6b:61:af:bd:c0:fc:f7:c2:37:a2:c2:
         7f:cc:de:98:a4:61:25:e2:78:b2:ab:94:31:0d:8f:2f:92:7b:
         4a:4f:5b:1c:c2:e8:bd:43:cb:78:0e:f2:4b:b9:a5:54:0c:46:
         0f:b0:92:f8:3c:57:08:6a:df:a4:cd:78:63:23:2f:13:12:7f:
         89:7f:3d:c0:dd:c7:33:8d:55:76:10:38:47:2b:16:ce:d0:93:
         c4:9e:28:42:1e:2b:f4:78:15:dd:89:1e:67:a5:a1:a1:13:30:
         9a:2f:60:82:71:db:29:47:af:e7:61:71:1c:d6:72:27:61:17:
         e1:31:aa:ee:84:0d:53:f8:66:18:49:34:5d:fb:50:fb:4f:c7:
         b5:a1:8e:34:86:81:25:ad:31:d4:5c:9e:da:8d:08:85:a9:91:
         c6:f8:83:c7:23:57:11:04:dc:90:5a:c9:5a:bf:dd:3c:9c:6a:
         17:d8:d0:1f
```

### Environment

```
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

# curl --version
curl 7.57.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.57.0 NSS/3.28.4 zlib/1.2.7 libpsl/0.7.0 (+libicu/50.1.2) libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.21.1
Release-Date: 2017-11-29
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy Metalink PSL
```

### Similar issues

Link below showed the same issue but could not see the solution.

- [Stenoread certificate error #124](https://github.com/google/stenographer/issues/124)

Comment: what does the -k option give ?

Comment: Hello @EugèneAdell, skipping the TLS server certificate verification misses the point of this issue...

Comment: The goal is to know which certificate (client or server) generates this problem, thus the -k test. With openssl please try the -cert and -key options as you did for the other tests.

Comment: Side note: `--trace-ascii -` (with the final - meaning _"to stdout"_) instead of `-iv` might show extra details. With lots of garbage, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [answer from Steffen Ullrich](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176177/), the behaviour of curl is correct because the certificate cannot be a CA certificate due to the eKU limiting the purpose of the cert to a server certificate.

```
X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
    TLS Web Server Authentication
```

[This Mozilla Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1049176) explains.